# Python: Slice list into sublists, every time element begins with specific substring

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I want to slice list into sublists, every time element begins with specific substring.

So say I have:

```
a = ['XYthe', 'cat' , 'went', 'XYto', 'sleep','XYtoday','ok']
b = 'XY'
```

And want to return:

```
a1 = ['XYthe', 'cat', 'went']
a2 = ['XYto', 'sleep']
a3 = ['XYtoday', 'ok']
```

can anyone help?
Thank you!

Comment: It would help to know what you have already tried and why the results were unsatisfactory

Comment: *Can anyone help?* Yes, of course.  What is the *question*? You have merely stated what you wanted to do, but what is the problem? It would be helpful to see a [MCVE] of what you have tried so far.

Comment: The question is in the title.

Comment: @nicholishen that's an objective, not a question.

Comment: @Idlehands I'm not arguing that it's a good question, but it's implicit nonetheless. How do you slice a list into sub-lists every time an element begins with x sub-string?

Comment: I think most everybody can understand what OP is trying to achieve, that much is clear.  But the issue is this is basically a code request, we were given a mission statement, not a *question* by definition.  The only real *question* is *"can anyone help"* in which case I already answered, yes.  OP is by no means a newbie so we should have some expectation beyond the typical "please complete your [tour] and see [ask]..."

Comment: Use list comprehension. See my answer

Comment: lol..thank you to those who answered me without me needing to spend 20minutes typing a question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = ['XYthe', 'cat' , 'went', 'XYto', 'sleep','XYtoday','ok']
b = 'XY'

final_list = []
for word in a:
    if word.startswith(b):            # if the word starts with 'XY'...
        final_list.append([word])    # ...then make a new sublist
    else:
        final_list[-1].append(word)  # otherwise, add the word to the last sublist so far

print(final_list)
# [['XYthe', 'cat', 'went'], ['XYto', 'sleep'], ['XYtoday', 'ok']]
```

If the first element of `a` doesn't contain `b`, the code will raise an `IndexError`. This is intentional - you could use it to validate that `a` and `b` are valid inputs to this snippet of code.

Comment: better to use `str.startswith(b)`

Comment: oh, forgot that existed. Changed.

Comment: I have provided an answer using list comprehension and using startswith

Answer (score 1):

### Use **list comprehension** with **if/else:**

```
a = ['XYthe', 'cat' , 'went', 'XYto', 'sleep','XYtoday','ok']
b = 'XY'

# Use list comprehension
emp = []
[emp.append([i]) if i.startswith(b) else emp[-1].append(i) for i in a]

print(emp)
[['XYthe', 'cat', 'went'], ['XYto', 'sleep'], ['XYtoday', 'ok']]

print(emp[0])
['XYthe', 'cat', 'went']
```

Comment: While it's tempting, you shouldn't use list comprehension for these sort of scenarios.  A simple `for` loop would have been better.  This just ends up creating an empty `list` for no reason.

Comment: Even in the loop case, you will need to initiate an empty (output) list.

Comment: That's not the point... The list comprehension it's also generating a list of `None`s, which is useless.

Comment: Yes. for this I agree. I just provided another way to accomplish the task.